# Login page, not working

Tags: php, mysqli

I am still learning php and i stuck on an error that i can not find.
So i have a simple form with an email and password. I am hashing the password with a random salt key and sha512 and the hased password is behind the variable "p".

Here is the html code:

```
    <form action="includes/process_login.php" method="post" name="login_form">
        <input placeholder="Email address" type="text" name="email" id="email">
        <input placeholder="Password" type="password" name="password" id="password">
        <button class="button" onclick="formhash(this.form, this.form.password);">Login</button>
    </form>
```

Okay and here is the js file with the function:

```
function formhash(form, password) {
// Create a new element input, this will be our hashed password field. 
var p = document.createElement("input");

// Add the new element to our form. 
form.appendChild(p);
p.name = "p";
p.type = "hidden";
p.value = hex_sha512(password.value);

// Make sure the plaintext password doesn't get sent. 
password.value = "";

// Finally submit the form. 
form.submit();
}
```

I have the query here:

```
function login($email, $password, $mysqli) {
// Using prepared statements means that SQL injection is not possible. 
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT id, password, salt 
    FROM users
   WHERE email = ?
    LIMIT 1")) {
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $email);  // Bind "$email" to parameter.
    $stmt->execute();    // Execute the prepared query.
    $stmt->store_result();

    // get variables from result.
    $stmt->bind_result($user_id, $db_password, $salt);
    $stmt->fetch();

    // hash the password with the unique salt.
    $password = hash('sha512', $password . $salt);
```

And the process_login.php file:

```
if (isset($_POST['email'], $_POST['p'])) {
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['p']; // The hashed password.

    if (login($email, $password, $mysqli) == false) {
        // Login success 
        header('Location: ../desk.php');
    } else {
        // Login failed 
        header('Location: ../index.php?error=1');
    }
} else {
    // The correct POST variables were not sent to this page. 
    echo 'Invalid Request';
}
```

And i think that the error is somewhere in the process_login.php file but i cant find it. Everything seems fine to me, but when i try to login with some existing credentials i see: "Invalid Request" which means that the variables were not send and it is a mistery for me why...

Comment: NEVER hash with sha512, NEVER build your own login system unless you know exactly what you do. Please have a look here: http://php-login.net

Comment: Did you pass the data into php when submitting form?

Comment: Have you print_r'd `$_POST` to see exactly what is posted to the script?

If `$_POST['p']` is not set, the problem is in your javascript, so print_r'ing `$_POST` on the first line of `process_login.php` is the best place to start

Comment: Just for the record, your code checks for `login(...) == false` for login success. This is not necessarily wrong, just surprising.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend not to hash your password with javascript since javascript is executing on client side. So users can manipulate the input!

I recommend to hash the password with php (server side). Maybe with `md5` or something else.
Remove the `onClick` event in the form:

```
<form action="includes/process_login.php" method="post" name="login_form">
    <input placeholder="Email address" type="text" name="email" id="email">
    <input placeholder="Password" type="password" name="password" id="password">
    <button class="button" type="submit">Login</button>
</form>
```

After that you can simply delete the javascript function `formhash`.
Then you have to change the PHP-Script:

**process_login.php**

```
if (isset($_POST['email'], $_POST['password'])) {
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = hash('sha512', $_POST['password']); // The hashed password (sha512)

    if (login($email, $password, $mysqli) == false) {
        // Login success 
        header('Location: ../desk.php');
    } else {
        // Login failed 
        header('Location: ../index.php?error=1');
    }
} else {
    // The correct POST variables were not sent to this page. 
    echo 'Invalid Request';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are severely misusing the hash function. When your function sends a hash of the password, this hash effectively becomes a password. That is your essentially achieving *nothing* by hashing the password before transmition.

If you want a secure login form you should have communications to your site encrypted with TLS (HTTPS).

An alternative is [Secure remote password](http://srp.stanford.edu/) but this is surely too complex to implement.

Comment: Well i also have a file sha512.js, but now i will check if everything is fine without the hash

Comment: @user3811520 Don’t. There is *no* point in hashing the password in JavaScript.